# Auth0 Add Custom Claims to User Profile

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0

I want Auth0 to send some additional info in the user profile. So I created the following rule:

```
function (user, context, callback) {
  user.app_metadata = user.app_metadata || {};
  user.app_metadata.test = "some info here";
    auth0.users.updateAppMetadata(user.user_id, user.app_metadata)
      .then(function() {
        context.idToken['https://example.com/test'] = user.app_metadata.test;
        callback(null, user, context);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        callback(err);
      });
}
```

However, instead of receiving this (which I expected):

```
{
  user_metadata: {
   test: "some customer id"
  }
  nickname: "afaafa11fdf"
  name: "afaafa11fdf@bob.com"
}
```

I receive this:

```
{
  https://example.com/test: "some customer id"
  nickname: "afaafa11fdf"
  name: "afaafa11fdf@bob.com"
}
```

I have been following [these guidelines here](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/scope-custom-claims?_ga=2.125653578.1314846914.1584112305-222595504.1582535442#custom-claims).

Comment: The article mentions something about using the Auth0 management API to set application-specific information for this user.  Did you do that?  Maybe it needs that to associate the information you're tacking on as user metadata versus just appending some arbitrary key-value to the object.  Another thing: does the namespace match what your app domain is?  (surely it's not example.com)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the managment API to set the metadata. That's basically what `auth0.users.updateAppMetadata` does. The information is stored correctly in the user profile as well. I guess what's meant is the Auth0-domain then? e.g. `mysite.auth0.com` ? I will try that! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Auth0 and apparently that's the desired behaviour. I expected the wrong result, but what I describe above and did in fact receive is correct. So for anyone with this question, you will in the end receive something along these lines:

```
{
  https://example.com/test: "some customer id"
  nickname: "afaafa11fdf"
  name: "afaafa11fdf@bob.com"
}
```